# PlutusPlayground [high REDEEM fees]

Tags: cardano, plutus

I'm learning writing smart contracts in the **PlutusPlayground** and am getting excessively high fees when redeeming tokens from the example scripts (over 3000 ADA).

Does anyone know why this might happen?
I've seen a couple tutorials going through these examples and nobody seems to be experiencing this.

**It's not a problem while learning/testing in the playground but I'm concerned I'm not getting real data on the potential costs of running plutus contracts (or my setup is just messed up).**

I've attached screenshots from 2 examples:

1. Error - insufficient funds in the redeemer's wallet
2. Working - gave redeemer over 3160 ADA to cover the fees

( 1 )
[image: Seemingly correct]
[image: Spent ADA, but not redeemed]
[image: Error]

( 2 )

[image: Higher initial balance]
[image: Transaction completed successfully with excessive redeem fee]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Ada/Lovelace ratio is 1:1000000 so the fee was really nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to cover fees you are using lovelace, not ADAs. [Lovelace definition](https://docs.cardano.org/glossary#lovelace)

> **lovelace**
>
> the smallest unit of ada, equivalent to one millionth of one ada. A lovelace is to ada what a satoshi is to bitcoin.

As you said:
1 ADA = 1000000 lovelace